# Finance specific modules for Python in 2017?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, python

I'm currently using Pandas, Numpy, Scikit-learn, Matplolib but I feel those are just general data analytics related modules.

I was taking a Couresa course that used QSTK for specific quant related tasks, but the last update seems to be 2013 or so. I'm looking for tools that create portfolios, different ways to allocate my money (by sectors, by individual stocks), market simulator,  aware of Earnings events etc.   Any tools that will make any of these easier?

Comment: QuantLib and Quandl?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at this: https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/awesome-quant

Comment: It is a bit of a grab bag ("an assortment of miscellaneous items"), but there are many items that look like they might be worthwhile. For the portfolio analytics stuff, consider PyFolio.

Comment: Yeah, I had looked at this before I made an OP, but he just threw everything he could find into that list.